# Fixed footnotes don't work as expected within minipages

Tags: footnotes

As pointed out by the following example, fixed footnotes don't work as
expected within `minipage`'s: the footnote mark of their occurrences
(except the 1<sup>st</sup> one) is equal to the current value of the (normal)
footnote counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixfoot}

\DeclareFixedFootnote{\foo}{A first fixed footnote (foo).}
\DeclareFixedFootnote{\baz}{A second fixed footnote (baz).}

\begin{document}
\section{Fixed footnote not within a minipage: okay}
\begin{itemize}
\item Foo\foo{}.
\item Foo\foo{}.
\item Bar\footnote{A non fixed footnote.}.
\end{itemize}
\section{Fixed footnote within a minipage: not okay}
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{10cm}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Baz\baz{}.
    \item Baz\baz{}.
    \item Baz\baz{}.
    \item Baz\baz{}.
    \item Baz\baz{}.
    \item Bar\footnote{A non fixed footnote.}.
    \item Bar\footnote{A non fixed footnote.}.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Do you see a workaround?

Comment: I am not sure if this will not break any thing but you can try `\patchcmd\@fixed@footnote{\the\c@footnote}{\ifx\@footnotetext\@mpfootnotetext{\noexpand\itshape\alph{mpfootnote}}\else\the\c@footnote\fi}{}{}` with `etoolbox`

Comment: @touhami In your code, there are strange invisible spaces between the "x" and the "t" in `\@footnotetex‌​t`, between the "n" and the "o" in `\n‌​oexpand` and between the "t" and the "h" in `\t‌​he` that lead to `\@curr@enc` to be "Undefined control sequence". Removing them still gives an error: "! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> \c@�".

Comment: I don't not know where these spaces come from. Try  again `\patchcmd\@fixed@footnote{\the\c@footnote}{%
\ifx\@footnotetext\@mpfootnotetext{\noexpand\itshape\alph{mpfootnote}}\else\the\c@footnote\fi}{}{‌​}` or try to type it you're self :-)

Comment: @touhami There was still a double invisible space between the "h" and the "{" in `\alph{mpfootnote}` in your first code and other ones in your second code: very strange! But, after removing all these spaces in both codes, everything's okay now :) Please provide your solution as an answer hence I can accept it. Maybe, in case of edge effects, others would suggest other solution(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `etoolbox` package to patch the command `\@fixed@footnote`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixfoot}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@fixed@footnote{\the\c@footnote}{%
\ifx\@footnotetext\@mpfootnotetext{\noexpand\itshape\alph{mpfootnote}}\else\the\c@footnote\fi}{}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareFixedFootnote{\foo}{A first fixed footnote (foo).}
\DeclareFixedFootnote{\baz}{A second fixed footnote (baz).}

\begin{document}
\section{Fixed footnote not within a minipage: okay}
\begin{itemize}
\item Foo\foo{}.
\item Foo\foo{}.
\item Bar\footnote{A non fixed footnote.}.
\end{itemize}
\section{Fixed footnote within a minipage: not okay}
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{10cm}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Baz\baz{}.
    \item Baz\baz{}.
    \item Baz\baz{}.
    \item Baz\baz{}.
    \item Baz\baz{}.
    \item Bar\footnote{A non fixed footnote.}.
    \item Bar\footnote{A non fixed footnote.}.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]